# Mercurial windows server 2008

Tags: mercurial, clone

I have the all-in-one download with TortoiseHg 2.6.1 and Mercurial 2.4.1 installed on windows server 2k8. I created a repository, served it on port 8000. There are no mercurial configuration files setup right now for this repository. No global config files either. When I try to clone this repos through eclipse (MercruialEclipse plugin) from a remote computer over the internet, I get:

```
abort: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

What does this mean?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. The command syntax was incorrect. The incorrect syntax I was using was

```
hg clone http://www.xyz.com:8000/<dirname for the repo clone>
```

The correct command is:

```
    hg clone http://www.xyz.com:8000/ <dirname for the repo clone>
```

Should also mention that I am using version 2.3.2(mercurial)